# Why is my ajax element immediately losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, autocomplete

I'm trying to add an autocomplete option to the title field in Wordpress - the titles of one of my custom document types will often (but not always) have a standard name.

I've hooked into Wordpress to add a `div` with an id of `suggestions` below `title`, and add a javascript `onKeyUp` event to title telling it to make an ajax request to a page that suggests names based on what's typed so far. This is all working fine.

Currently, however, I'm only able to select the suggestions via a mouseclick (which then uses `val` to update the value of `#title`. I'd also like users to be able to use the arrow keys to select a suggestion, a la Google.

I'm working on building this by giving each suggestion focus (each line is a `li` element with a dynamically generated `tabindex`.)

This works for a split second - the expected element gets the focus - but then it immediately loses it, going back to the `body`. Why is this happening?

Code for gethint.php:

```
<?php

$sofar = stripslashes($_GET['sofar']); // This is important as otherwise the url gets confused and won't work on anything with an apostrophe in it.

$common_file_names = array(
    "Here's suggestion 1",
    "This is suggestion 2",
    "Suggestion 3");
if(strlen($_GET['sofar'])>1) { //Ignores single letters
    echo '<ul id="autocomplete">';
    $tabindex=0;
    foreach ($common_file_names as $suggestion) {
        if(false !== stripos($suggestion, $sofar)) : ?>
            <li 
            tabindex="<?=$tabindex?>" 
            onClick="acceptSuggestion('<?=addslashes($suggestion)?>')"
            onBlur="console.log('Lost focus!'); console.log(document.activeElement);";
            ><?=$suggestion?></li>
        <?php $tabindex++; endif;

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

JS Code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

window.onload = function () {
    $( "<div id='suggestions'></div>" ).insertAfter( "#title" );

    $(document).on('keydown', '#title', function (){
          var hint_slash = this.value;
          showHint(hint_slash);
          checkKey(event);
    });



    $(document).on('focus', '#acf-field-extranet_client_area', function (){
         clearSuggestions();
    });
    $(document).on('focus', '#acf-field-extranet_document_type', function (){
         clearSuggestions();
    });
    $(document).on('focus', '#acf-date_picker', function (){
         clearSuggestions();
    });
    $(document).on('focus', '#acf-file-value', function (){
         clearSuggestions();
    });


    console.log("Scripts loaded successfully");
}

function showHint(str) { //If the user has typed 2 or more characters, this function looks for possible matches among common document names to speed up data entry.
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("suggestions").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/gethint.php?sofar=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}


function acceptSuggestion(str) {
    $('#title').val(str); //Puts the clicked suggestion into the title box.
    clearSuggestions();
}

function clearSuggestions() {
    showHint(""); //Clears suggestions.
}

function checkKey(event) {
    console.log('Key press: ' + event.keyCode);
    if(40 == event.keyCode) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stops scrolling.
        var autocomplete =  $("#autocomplete");
        $(autocomplete.children('li:nth-child(' + 2 + ')')).focus() ;
        console.log(document.activeElement);
        }

    }
```

This is just test code currently, hence always setting focus to the 3rd child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @evilunix's answer, I realised that each keystroke was resetting the `#suggestions` div, which meant that it could never hold focus (or keep an appended class etc).

So, wrote a new function called checkKey:

```
function checkKey(e) {  
    if(e.which == 38) {
        // up key
        e.preventDefault(); //Stops scrolling and cursor movement.
        var active = $('#suggestions li.active');
        if(active.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            active.prev().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#suggestions li:last').addClass('active');
        }
    } else if(e.which == 40) {
        // down key
        e.preventDefault(); //Stops scrolling and cursor movement.
        var active = $('#suggestions li.active');
        if(active.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            active.next().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#suggestions li:first').addClass('active');
        }
    } else if(e.which == 13) {
        //Return key
        e.preventDefault(); //Stops form submission.
        acceptSuggestion(document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].innerHTML);
    } else {
        console.log(e.which);
        showHint($('#title').val());    
    }
}
```

and changed `#title`'s onKeydown event to:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#title', function (){
        checkKey(event);
});
```

Now `#suggestions` only refreshes if the keystroke is not an up arrow, down arrow or return, and on a return runs `acceptSuggestion` on whichever `li` has the `active` class.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try focus on the suggestions. You'll have to add the keychecking code to every suggestion in this case, because the input will lose focus. Instead, create a CSS class for the "focused" suggestion, remove the class on key up/down and add it to the previous/next suggestion...

```
 $input.keyup(function(e) {

    if(e.which == 38) {
        // up key
        var active = $('.suggestions li.active');
        if(active.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            active.prev().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.suggestions li:last').addClass('active');
        }
    } else if(e.which == 40) {
        // down key
        var active = $('.suggestions li.active');
        if(active.length) {
            active.removeClass('active');
            active.next().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.suggestions li:first').addClass('active');
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: This still has the same problem: the element gets the class 'active' for a split second, then loses it. I suspect that showHint is refreshing suggestions even on a down arrow key press.

Comment: Ah, yes it will be. The simplest solution is to check that you never submit the same query two times in a row, by storing the last query which you successfully got suggestions for. You should use this code instead of focusing though, otherwise your input will lose the focus.